# Is this a good architecture for my web application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a website in ASP.NET MVC, but I am not really sure how I should organize things. N-Tier applications seem to work nice, but since I am a beginner programmer it is pretty hard to understand. I just want to create a small web application where people can login and create pages. In these pages they can add others things. The database won’t be bigger than 10 tables I think. Even though it is a small application, I would like to use some best practices that N-Tier applications use.

Is this a good approach? Or is it very wrong? :

**Project.Models**

Models that represent the entities in my database.

**Project.DAL**

Interfaces and implementations for my repositories and unit of work. Also my NHibernate mappings.

**Project.BLL**

Interfaces and implementations for my services.

**Project.UI.Web.MVC**

My controllers, viewmodels and views. The controllers get data from services and pass data (viewmodels) to views so I think it’s part of the UI.

Comment: as per Gaz there is no hard fast rule, just one suggestion Project.UI.Web.MVC can be Project.UI.Web only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules about how to organise your project.

That looks pretty logical to me and seems to follow a lot of hte examples that i have seen across the internet.

All that matters is that its logical to you and your team in my opinion.

Take a look at this link as well, might be a lot of useful information for you there:

[Best practices for MVC architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30348/best-practices-for-mvc-architecture)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a neat layering.

Define clearly on what goes in DAL, BLL and Web.MVC. Because people can have difference in opinion in what goes into business logic and ui logic, I suggest to have a weekly review of what has went into each layers - to start with.

One suggestion is to call Project.UI.Web instead of Project.UI.Web.MVC.